# Similar to Eisenstein's criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

I know the 'Eisenstein's criterion'.

**I know that it states "($p\nmid a_{n}$), [$p\mid a_i$ for ($0\le i\le n-1$)], ($p^2\nmid a_0$)".**

I know regular way, but I hope to second pf way.

> Let $f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+\cdots +a_{n}x^{n}$,  deg $f(x)\ge1$.
>
> For some prime $p$, **($p\nmid a_0$)** and **$p\mid a_i$ for ($1\le i \le n$)**, **($p^2\nmid a_n$)**.
>
> Then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

**My Proof.**
Suppose that $f(x)$ is reducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Then $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ for some $g(x),h(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$ (by Gauss lemma), where $g(x)=b_{0}+b_{1}x+\cdots +b_{r}x^{r}$,  $\deg g(x)\ge1$, $h(x)=c_{0}+c_{1}x+\cdots +c_{s}x^{s}$,  $\deg h(x)\ge1$.

So, $$f(x)=g(x)h(x)=(b_{0}+b_{1}x+\cdots +b_{r}x^{r})(c_{0}+c_{1}x+\cdots +c_{s}x^{s})=b_0c_0+\cdots+b_r c_sx^{r+s}.$$

Then $a_0=b_0 c_0$ and $a_n=b_r c_s$.

Since **($p\nmid a_0$)** and **$p\mid a_i$ for ($1\le i \le n$)**, **($p^2\nmid a_n$)**,

**($p\nmid b_0 c_0$)** =>  **($p\nmid b_0$) and ($p\nmid c_0$)**.

**($p^2\nmid b_r c_s$)** => **either ($p\nmid b_r$) or ($p\nmid c_s$)**

Say $p\mid b_r$ and **($p\nmid c_s$)**.

Let $t$ be the largest integer s.t. ($p\nmid b_t$) and $p\mid b_i$ for ($ 0\lt t \lt i$).

**Why largest integer? I thinks set $t$ is smallest integer...**

then $a_t=(b_0 c_t +\cdots +b_{t-1} c_1)+b_t c_0$.

Since $p\mid a_t$, then $p\mid b_t c_0$ -Contradiction-

**$p\mid b_0 c_t +\cdots +b_{t-1} c_1$ is true? Why?**

Set ($p\nmid b_t$) and $p\mid b_i$ for ($ 0\lt t \lt i$).

It means that ($p\mid b_{t+1}$, $p\mid b_{t+2}$, $p\mid b_{t+3}$, $\dots$).

I don't know it... plz help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to show the Eisenstein criterion with the roles of $a_0$ and $a_n$ swapped? Note that one form follows from the other by noting that $x^{\deg f}f(\frac1x)$ is irreducible iff $f(x)$ is.

Comment: other pf way, 
Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1 x+⋯+a_n x_n$, deg $f(x)≥1$.
for some prime $p$ , NOT $(p|a0)$ and $p|a_i$ for $(1≤i≤n)$, NOT $(p^2|a_n)$.
then $f(x)$ is irreducible over ℚ.

this statement is written in my text book (But not exist pf)
I hope to pf it

Comment: i thinks about your answer, you'r means that $x^n$=>${1 \over x}^n$? if it can, i appreciate you!

Comment: OMG thanks! man!